# Compare values from one column to another all rows

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe like:

```
df1

right     left

[a,b]     [c,d,e,f]

[b,c]     [a,d,e,f]

[c,d,e,f] [a,b]
```

Line 1 and 3 are basically same and I want to remove the duplicates.

Is their any way to do this?
The data is structured in this way only.

I tried running below command I found but since these are lists, it throws an error:

df1.duplicated(subset = ['right', 'left'], keep = False)

error: unhashable type :list

Comment: What is `print (df.head())` ?

Comment: That's the output. right and left are two columns and that's the data

Comment: I ask about structure, there are lists?

Comment: yes they are lists and hence wen i try to run : df1.duplicated(subset = ['right', 'left'], keep = False), it throws an error with unhashable type : list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create hashable type tuple for both columns, sorting in list comprehension and test duplicates by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
L = [tuple(map(tuple, sorted(x))) for x in df[['right','left']].to_numpy()]
m = pd.Series(L, index=df.index).duplicated(keep = False)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```